# How to create a diff column with the previous period value in python?

Tags: python

I'm just trying to create a column in my dataframe with the difference of the column value and the same column of the previous month. In case the previous month doesn't exist, don't calculate the difference.

[Result table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oodRi.png)

```
df_ranking['cat_race'] = df_ranking.groupby(df_ranking['ID'], df_ranking['DATE'])['POINTS'].shift(1)
```

But the error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jhoyo/PycharmProjects/Tennis-Ranking/venv/ranking_2_db.py", line 95, in <module>
    df_ranking['cat_race'] = df_ranking.groupby(df_ranking['licencia'], df_ranking['date'])['puntos'].shift(1)
  File "C:\Users\jhoyo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 7629, in groupby
    axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
  File "C:\Users\jhoyo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 351, in _get_axis_number
    axis = cls._AXIS_ALIASES.get(axis, axis)
  File "C:\Users\jhoyo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1816, in __hash__
    ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: Change your group by to `df_ranking.groupby(['ID', 'DATE'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define groupby like this===>

```
df_ranking['cat_race'] = df_ranking.groupby(['ID','Date'])['POINTS'].shift(1)
```

Hope it will work